# Having trouble parsing JSON stream,

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am able to connect to vendor's web API using basic authentication and HTTPWebResponse in C# .Net.  I am able to get the JSON stream in the StreamReader but when parsing the JSON, I am getting null values and not being able to get data elements in individual strings or variables.  Please see the attached JSON file and help...

Here is my code...

```
 username = "****";
 var password = "***";
 var url = "*****";
 var encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username  + ":" + password));
 var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
 webRequest.Method = "GET";
 webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
 webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";


 var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
 var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
 string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Tried every solution out there but having trouble.  Below is some of my JSON stream.

> {"status":"success","message":"The request for notes has been processed successfully.  100 records have been returned.","data":[{"noteId":"0000","studentId":"000000","advisorId":"0000111","dateCreated":"01/20/2015","studentStatus":"On path","noteBody":"This is a test note, and it is for a particular student.  It is for student 000000","edited":"N","dateEdited":"N/A","privateNote":"N","removed":"N","removedDate":"N/A","displayDate":"01/20/2015","noteCreatedWithReminder":"N","noteCreatedWithStatusChange":"N"},{"noteId":"0001","studentId":"000001","advisorId":"0000111","dateCreated":"01/20/2015","studentStatus":"In progress","noteBody":"This is a test note, and it is for a particular student.  It is for student 000001","edited":"N","dateEdited":"N/A","privateNote":"N","removed":"N","removedDate":"N/A","displayDate":"01/20/2015","noteCreatedWithReminder":"N","noteCreatedWithStatusChange":"Y"}

Comment: "not being able to get data elements in individual strings or variables." --Hpw are you extracting those individual strings or variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using libraries such as [`JSON.net`](http://json.net) it will make it easier to parse, all you need to do is create model classes:

```
public class Note
{
    public string noteId { get; set; }
    public string studentId { get; set; }
    public string advisorId { get; set; }
    public string dateCreated { get; set; }
    public string studentStatus { get; set; }
    public string noteBody { get; set; }
    public string edited { get; set; }
    public string dateEdited { get; set; }
    public string privateNote { get; set; }
    public string removed { get; set; }
    public string removedDate { get; set; }
    public string displayDate { get; set; }
    public string noteCreatedWithReminder { get; set; }
    public string noteCreatedWithStatusChange { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Note> notes { get; set; }
}
```

then this is how your parse it

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
Console.WriteLine("status =" + response.status);
```

Comment: This works great!  How to I get the List (notes) bind to a GridView?  Sorry, new here.